# How to handle pending call that is cancelled by Caller (CallKit)

Tags: swift, xcode, voip, callkit

I made a voice chat feature into my apps. And I have a problem with CallKit. My EndCallAction Request isn't consistenly working right now such as:

When EndCallAction did triggered via **callController.request**

> **Success with transaction.**

But it also happen to error sometimes like this:

> Error requesting transaction:
>   Error     Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=4
>   "(null)".

The code 4 error indicator which seems to be null UUID. But I did some debugging and found my UUIDs are there.

> Call Ended Printing description of withUUID: 
>   45C55D34-EB5D-49CF-A13D-80A4CD2FA4C5  Transaction UUID:
>   45C55D34-EB5D-49CF-A13D-80A4CD2FA4C5

These error only happen from time to time, let's say I'm misscalling for like 20 times, it happen like 3-6 times.

Please tell me how should I end **incoming call** when the **Caller** decided to **End the Call** before the **Callee** answered the call.

Comment: Please verify CXCallController & CXProviderConfiguration not getting initialised multiple times.

Comment: @RJVKumar it works, turns out I configured CXProviderConfiguration everytime Im calling CXProvider. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sureCXProviderConfiguration only configured once.

It worked now. Thanks

Comment: bro can share the solution how the device get signal that the caller end the call and how ended by reportcall function